# Keras multi-output: How to apply class weight to one output, without affecting other outputs

Tags: keras

I have a multi-output put model that shares the same backend. I have applied class weights to one of the outputs, and this has resulted in improved results in that particular output. However, it has negatively affected other outputs (reduction in accuracy). This could have happened since output with class weights could have influenced the weights in backend model, which are shared by all other outputs.

Is there a way to fix this?